# fprintf cause segmentation fault core dump

Tags: c, linux, segmentation-fault, coredump

This is my code in file **a.c**:

```
int auto_reboot() {
    char str[1000];
    char buf[1000];

    snprintf(str, sizeof(str), "/proc/%d/exe", getpid()); 
    readlink(str, buf, sizeof(str));
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("/etc/systemd/system/watchddog.service", "w");
    fprintf(fp, "[Unit]\nDescription=nginx - high performance web server\n[Service]\nType=forking\nRestart=always\nExecStart=\n[Install]\nWantedBy=multi-user.target");
    fclose(fp);

    return 1;
}
```

How come `fprintf` causes segmentation fault core dump?

I tried to change it to `fputs`, but still get the same error?

Comment: You didn't check that `fopen()` succeeded.  Unless you're running as `root`, it failed, so `fp` is null, which leads `fprintf()` to generate a segmentation fault.

Comment: @Neverwin Never call `open` or `fopen` without checking the return value to see if it succeeded.  These calls fail all the time, typically because or permission problems or path problems.  Any code that fails to check for it should not be used.

Answer (score 0):

The program has undefined behavior if `fopen` fails to open the file and returns `NULL`. Passing a null `FILE` pointer to `fprintf` or `fputs` has undefined behavior because these functions expect a valid pointer and do not check for null.

`fopen` may fail for multiple reasons, eg: if the process is not run as root.

Test the return value of `fopen` and report the problem with an explicit error message.

Also that `readlink` may fail, especially if `/proc/xxx/exe` is not implemented as a symbolic link on the target system.

Here is a modified version with error checking:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int auto_reboot(void) {
    char str[100];
    char buf[1000];

    snprintf(str, sizeof str, "/proc/%d/exe", getpid()); 
    if (readlink(str, buf, sizeof buf) <= 0)
        strcpy(buf, str);

    const char *filename = "/etc/systemd/system/watchddog.service";
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "w");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot open %s: %s\n", filename, strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }
    fprintf(fp, "[Unit]\n"
                "Description=nginx - high performance web server\n"
                "[Service]\n"
                "Type=forking\n"
                "Restart=always\n"
                "ExecStart=\n"
                "[Install]\n"
                "WantedBy=multi-user.target\n");
    fclose(fp);
    return 1;
}
```